# Contextual eval in clojure

Tags: clojure, macros

Here is an example from joy of clojure chapter 8:

```
(defn contextual-eval [ctx expr]
  (let [new-expr
        `(let [~@(mapcat (fn [[k v]]
                           [k `'~v])
                         ctx)]
           ~expr)]
    (pprint new-expr)
    (eval new-expr)))
(pprint (contextual-eval '{a 1 b 2} '(+ a b)))
```

I find the ``'` part quite perplexing, what's it for?

I also tried to modify the function a bit:

```
(defn contextual-eval [ctx expr]
  (let [new-expr
        `(let [~@(mapcat (fn [[k v]]
                           [k `~v])
                         ctx)]
           ~expr)]
    (pprint new-expr)
    (eval new-expr)))
(pprint (contextual-eval '{a 1 b 2} '(+ a b)))


(defn contextual-eval [ctx expr]
  (let [new-expr
        `(let [~@(vec (apply 
                        concat 
                        ctx))]
           ~expr)]
    (pprint new-expr)
    (eval new-expr)))
(pprint (contextual-eval '{a 1 b 2} '(+ a b)))
```

All the versions above have similar effect. Why did the author choose to use `' then?

A more detailed look:

```
(use 'clojure.pprint)
(defmacro epprint [expr]
  `(do
     (print "==>")
     (pprint '~expr)
     (pprint ~expr)))
(defmacro epprints [& exprs]
  (list* 'do (map (fn [x] (list 'epprint x))
                  exprs)))

(defn contextual-eval [ctx expr]
  (let [new-expr
        `(let [~@(mapcat (fn [[k v]]
                           (epprints
                             (class v)
                             v
                             (class '~v)
                             '~v
                             (class `'~v)
                             `'~v
                             (class ctx)
                             ctx)
                           [k `~v])
                         ctx)]
           ~expr)]
    (pprint new-expr)
    (eval new-expr)))
(pprint (contextual-eval '{a (* 2 3) b (inc 11)} '(+ a b)))
```

This prints out the following in the repl:

```
==>(class v)
clojure.lang.PersistentList
==>v
(* 2 3)
==>(class '~v)
clojure.lang.PersistentList
==>'~v
~v
==>(class
 (clojure.core/seq
  (clojure.core/concat
   (clojure.core/list 'quote)
   (clojure.core/list v))))
clojure.lang.Cons
==>(clojure.core/seq
 (clojure.core/concat (clojure.core/list 'quote) (clojure.core/list v)))
'(* 2 3)
==>(class ctx)
clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap
==>ctx
{a (* 2 3), b (inc 11)}
==>(class v)
clojure.lang.PersistentList
==>v
(inc 11)
==>(class '~v)
clojure.lang.PersistentList
==>'~v
~v
==>(class
 (clojure.core/seq
  (clojure.core/concat
   (clojure.core/list 'quote)
   (clojure.core/list v))))
clojure.lang.Cons
==>(clojure.core/seq
 (clojure.core/concat (clojure.core/list 'quote) (clojure.core/list v)))
'(inc 11)
==>(class ctx)
clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap
==>ctx
{a (* 2 3), b (inc 11)}
==>new-expr
(clojure.core/let [a (* 2 3) b (inc 11)] (+ a b))
18
```

Again, using a single syntax quote for v seems to get the job done.

In fact, using `'v might cause you some trouble:

```
(defn contextual-eval [ctx expr]
  (let [new-expr
        `(let [~@(mapcat (fn [[k v]]
                           [k `'~v])
                         ctx)]
           ~expr)]
    (pprint new-expr)
    (eval new-expr)))
(pprint (contextual-eval '{a (inc 3) b (* 3 4)} '(+ a b)))

CompilerException java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to java.lang.Number, compiling:(/Users/kaiyin/personal_config_bin_files/workspace/typedclj/src/typedclj/macros.clj:14:22)
```

Answer (score 2):

`'~v is a way to return

```
(list 'quote v)
```

in this case quoting the actual value of v in the `let` expression, not the symbol itself.

IDK The Joy Of Clojure, but apparently the authors want to prevent forms passed in ctx from being evaluated in the expanded let form. E. g. `(contextual-eval '{a (+ 3 4)} 'a)` will return `(+ 3 4)` but `7` in your versions which are both identical in behavior.

Comment: Why quote it twice? Why first syntax-quote then quote?

Comment: If you didn't syntax-quote, you'd quote the literal symbol `v`. If you didn't quote, e. g. `~v, you wouldn't quote anything at all because all you do is quote and unquote right away.

Comment: Within the syntax-quote, v is the resolved symbol `your.ns/v`.

Answer (score 2):

Your modified versions have the same effect only because you're trying them on very simple data. Try instead with a mapping like `{'a 'x}`, a context in which the binding for `a` is the symbol `x`.

```
user> (defn contextual-eval [ctx expr]
        (let [new-expr
              `(let [~@(mapcat (fn [[k v]]
                                 [k `'~v])
                               ctx)]
                 ~expr)]
          (eval new-expr)))
#'user/contextual-eval
user> (contextual-eval {'a 'x} '(name a))
"x"
user> (defn contextual-eval [ctx expr]
        (let [new-expr
              `(let [~@(mapcat (fn [[k v]]
                                 [k `~v])
                               ctx)]
                 ~expr)]
          (eval new-expr)))
#'user/contextual-eval
user> (contextual-eval {'a 'x} '(name a))
; Evaluation aborted.
```

The problem is that in your version, by neglecting the quote, you are double-evaluating the values bound to your symbols: `x` *shouldn't* be evaluated, because the value is actually the symbol `x`. You get away with this double evaluation in your simple test cases, because 1 evaluates to itself: (eval (eval (eval 1))) would work fine too. But doing that with most data structures is wrong, because they have non-trivial evaluation semantics.

Note also that the following expressions are identical in all cases, so there's never a reason to write any of them but the first one:

````
x
`~x
`~`~x
```~`~~`~~x
````

If you syntax-quote and then immediately un-quote, you haven't accomplished anything. So, if you ever find yourself writing a quote followed by an unquote, this should be a big red flag that you are doing something wrong.